# Drag and Drop - Flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi3kn.jpg)I'm new to programming and I'm basically using YouTube and GPT when an error appears in my code.
In the image you can see that I have icons in a menu, I want it to be possible to drag these icons and for them to stay on the screen where I drop the icon. With the current code I can drag the icon, but it goes back to the menu and doesn't stay on the screen where I drop the icon

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print, library_private_types_in_public_api

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'DrawingWidget.dart'; // Certifique-se de que este arquivo existe e está correto

class BankPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BankPage({super.key});

  @override
  _BankPageState createState() => _BankPageState();
}

class DraggableOperatorIcon {
  final String iconPath;
  Offset position;

  DraggableOperatorIcon({required this.iconPath, required this.position});
}

class _BankPageState extends State<BankPage> {
  final Map<String, String> floorImages = {
    'ROOF': 'https://staticctf.ubisoft.com/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/3iRfs8bs7ZDzQLiXtWH5sk/3470781cd44b467f197271f8726cfc1b/r6-maps-bank-blueprint-4.jpg',
    '1ST FLOOR': 'https://staticctf.ubisoft.com/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/6ITkJP9lxHjVKzS9Ubcwtv/f8d74f4f67f2385b05144e906d4c3f80/r6-maps-bank-blueprint-2.jpg',
    'GROUND': 'https://staticctf.ubisoft.com/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/6ZcnTtEXcYt8CrMsjbCvSu/3e94cd919cae0d5d1cec5e94b01fd97f/r6-maps-bank-blueprint-1.jpg',
    'BASEMENT': 'https://staticctf.ubisoft.com/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/1DQ8HzVXAIpl5Flv1BNURw/93e625d47864c1a8eb0171f192a13078/r6-maps-bank-blueprint-3.jpg',
  };

  String currentFloor = 'ROOF';
  bool isHovering = false;

  final List<DraggableOperatorIcon> _droppedIcons = [];
       final List<String> attackOperatorIcons = [
 'assets/icons/operators/ATK/ace.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/amaru.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/ash.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/blackbeard.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/blitz.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/brava.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/buck.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/capitao.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/deimos.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/dokkaebi.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/finka.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/flores.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/fuze.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/glaz.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/gridlock.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/grim.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/hibana.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/iana.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/iq.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/jackal.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/kali.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/lion.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/maverick.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/montagne.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/nomad.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/osa.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/ram.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/sens.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/sledge.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/thatcher.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/thermite.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/twitch.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/ying.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/zero.png',
'assets/icons/operators/ATK/zofia.png',

    // Adicione os caminhos dos ícones de ataque
  ];

  final List<String> defenceOperatorIcons = [
    'assets/icons/operators/DEF/alibi.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/aruni.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/azami.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/bandit.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/castle.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/caveira.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/clash.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/doc.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/echo.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/ela.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/fenrir.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/frost.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/goyo.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/jager.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/kaid.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/kapkan.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/lesion.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/maestro.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/melusi.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/mira.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/mozzie.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/mute.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/nokk.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/oryx.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/pulse.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/rook.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/smoke.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/solis.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/tachanka.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/thorn.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/thunderbird.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/tubarao.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/valkyrie.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/vigil.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/wamai.png',
'assets/icons/operators/DEF/warden.png',



    // Adicione os caminhos dos ícones de defesa
  ];
  // Definição da classe DraggableOperatorIcon movida para fora da classe _BankPageState
  // Lista de ícones para operadores de ataque e defesa aqui...

  void _openOperatorsMenu() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.31,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                const TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'ATTACK'),
                    Tab(text: 'DEFENCE'),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      _buildOperatorsGrid(attackOperatorIcons),
                      _buildOperatorsGrid(defenceOperatorIcons),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


 Widget _buildOperatorsGrid(List<String> operatorIcons) {
  return GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 10,
      childAspectRatio: 1,
    ),
    itemCount: operatorIcons.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Draggable<String>(
        data: operatorIcons[index],
        feedback: Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          color: Color.fromARGB(0, 229, 28, 243),
          child: Image.asset(operatorIcons[index], fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 50, height: 50),
        ),
        childWhenDragging: Container(),
        child: Image.asset(operatorIcons[index], fit: BoxFit.cover),
      );
    },
  );
}

  void _openGadgetsMenu() {
    print('Abrindo menu de gadgets...');
  }

  Widget _movableIcon(DraggableOperatorIcon icon) {
    return Positioned(
      left: icon.position.dx,
      top: icon.position.dy,
      child: Draggable(
        data: icon,
        feedback: Material(
          type: MaterialType.transparency,
          child: Image.asset(icon.iconPath, width: 50, height: 50),
        ),
        childWhenDragging: Container(),
        onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
          setState(() {
            icon.position = offset;
          });
        },
        child: GestureDetector(
          // Permite mover o ícone após ele ser solto
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            setState(() {
              icon.position += details.delta;
            });
          },
          child: Image.asset(icon.iconPath, width: 50, height: 50),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bank'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.network(
              floorImages[currentFloor]!,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          const Positioned.fill(
            child: DrawingWidget(),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: MouseRegion(
              onEnter: (_) => setState(() => isHovering = true),
              onExit: (_) => setState(() => isHovering = false),
              child: Container(
                width: 50,
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            left: isHovering ? 0 : -250,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            width: 250,
            child: MouseRegion(
              onEnter: (_) => setState(() => isHovering = true),
              onExit: (_) => setState(() => isHovering = false),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: floorImages.keys.map((floor) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => setState(() {
                        currentFloor = floor;
                      }),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 60),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        floor,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          
          Positioned(
  bottom: 10,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "openOperatorsMenu", // Tag única
        onPressed: _openOperatorsMenu,
        child: const Icon(Icons.group),
      ),
      const SizedBox(width: 10), // Espaço entre os botões
      FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "openGadgetsMenu", // Tag única
        onPressed: _openGadgetsMenu,
        child: const Icon(Icons.wifi),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
..._droppedIcons.map(_movableIcon).toList(),
          // O DragTarget que cobre toda a tela
             Positioned.fill(
  child: DragTarget<String>(
    onWillAcceptWithDetails: (_BankPageState) => true,
   onAcceptWithDetails: (details) {
  final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
  final Offset localOffset = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.offset);
  setState(() {
    _droppedIcons.add(
      DraggableOperatorIcon(
        iconPath: details.data,
        position: localOffset - const Offset(25, 25),
      ),
    );
  });
},
    builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
      return Stack(
        children: _droppedIcons.map((icon) {
          return Positioned(
            left: icon.position.dx,
            top: icon.position.dy,
            child: Image.asset(icon.iconPath, width: 50, height: 50),
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    },
  ),
),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
}

// A classe DraggableOperatorIcon deve estar fora da classe _BankPageState
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZGik.jpg)
```